# Fetch youtube video title and category from url using youtube api v3

Tags: python, youtube

I'm a total beginner at this! I want to fetch the title of a youtube video and also it's category from the Url in python.

```
import lxml
from lxml import etree
youtube = etree.HTML(urllib.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQEOBZLx-Z8").read())
video_title = youtube.xpath("//span[@id='eow-title']/@title")
print ''.join(video_title)
```

Output : '12 Days of Christmas -  Christmas Carol'

I've tried the `lxml` module to obtain the title but it doesn't work for all videos and I wish to use the youtube api v3. But how do I start, I went through a lot of sites and tried to take help but I always get an error on my console. I have created the server key for my project at https://console.developers.google.com, what should I do now? I went through the official page but couldn't undestand much. Where should I start? I also looked at a couple of other SO questions and the codes didn't work for me.

```
 import urllib
 import simplejson

 id = 'KQEOBZLx-Z8'
 url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/%s?alt=json&v=2' % id

 json = simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))

 title = json['entry']['title']['$t']
 author = json['entry']['author'][0]['name']

 print "id:%s\nauthor:%s\ntitle:%s" % (id, author, title)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Is that really your key?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Which one?

Comment: `id`, also you do realise there is a python api?

Comment: The second code is just something I've copied from another SO question, although I did try to print json and "entry" was not a part of it! Please help if you can!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I think that's the video id.

Comment: yes it is, I realised that after

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Can you suggest something here?

Comment: I added an example, the moral of the story is to use the python api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the  data using the [google-api-client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation) lib, simple example:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.tools import argparser

# Set DEVELOPER_KEY to the API key value from the APIs & auth > Registered apps
# tab of
#   https://cloud.google.com/console
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
DEVELOPER_KEY = key
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"


def youtube_search(vid):
    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
                    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

    # Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
    # query term.
    search_response = youtube.search().list(
    part="snippet",
    relatedToVideoId=vid,
    type="video",
).execute()
print(search_response)
    print(search_response)


try:
    youtube_search("KQEOBZLx-Z8")
except HttpError as  e:
    print "An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content)
```

The valid parameters are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) and below that is another full example. You will need to have the *youtube data api enabled* and to have a *developer key*.

Using requests:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={id}&key={api_key}"
_id = "KQEOBZLx-Z8"
r = requests.get(url.format(id=_id, api_key=DEVELOPER_KEY))

print(r.json())
```

Which gives you:

```
{u'etag': u'"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/8KOFImC75qsfDbVWk53UnuxsQmo"',
 u'items': [{u'etag': u'"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/60ikaVqe2cge-D1XrdM2l0Bf4Jg"',
             u'id': u'KQEOBZLx-Z8',
             u'kind': u'youtube#video',
             u'snippet': {u'categoryId': u'1',
                          u'channelId': u'UC3djj8jS0370cu_ghKs_Ong',
                          u'channelTitle': u'HooplaKidz',
                          u'description': u'Check out http://vid.io/xovq for Non-Stop Children Songs!\nEveryone likes to enjoy festivals, so come and sing along to this beautiful 12 Days of Christmas which will be loved by one and all !!! \n\nLyrics to Sing Along :-\n-------------------------------------\nOn the first day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nA partridge in a pear tree.\n \nOn the second day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the third day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the fourth day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nFour calling birds, \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the fifth day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nFive golden rings, \nFour calling birds, \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the sixth day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nSix geese a-laying, \nFive golden rings, \nFour calling birds, \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the seventh day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nSeven swans a-swimming, \nSix geese a-laying, \nFive golden rings, \nFour calling birds, \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the eighth day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nEight maids a-milking, \nSeven swans a-swimming, \nSix geese a-laying, \nFive golden rings, \nFour calling birds, \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the ninth day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nNine ladies dancing, \nEight maids a-milking, \nSeven swans a-swimming, \nSix geese a-laying, \nFive golden rings, \nFour calling birds, \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the tenth day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nTen lords a-leaping, \nNine ladies dancing, \nEight maids a-milking, \nSeven swans a-swimming, \nSix geese a-laying, \nFive golden rings, \nFour calling birds, \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the eleventh day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nEleven pipers piping, \nTen lords a-leaping, \nNine ladies dancing, \nEight maids a-milking, \nSeven swans a-swimming, \nSix geese a-laying, \nFive golden rings, \nFour calling birds, \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the twelfth day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nTwelve drummers drumming, \nEleven pipers piping, \nTen lords a-leaping, \nNine ladies dancing, \nEight maids a-milking, \nSeven swans a-swimming, \nSix geese a-laying, \nFive golden rings, \nFour calling birds, \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree!  \n\nDownload Hooplakidz Songs on iTunes:\nhttp://itunes.apple.com/us/album/hoopla-kidz/id439987868\n\nBecome a Hooplakidz Fan on Facebook:\nhttp://www.facebook.com/hooplakidz',
                          u'liveBroadcastContent': u'none',
                          u'localized': {u'description': u'Check out http://vid.io/xovq for Non-Stop Children Songs!\nEveryone likes to enjoy festivals, so come and sing along to this beautiful 12 Days of Christmas which will be loved by one and all !!! \n\nLyrics to Sing Along :-\n-------------------------------------\nOn the first day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nA partridge in a pear tree.\n \nOn the second day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the third day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the fourth day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nFour calling birds, \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the fifth day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nFive golden rings, \nFour calling birds, \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the sixth day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nSix geese a-laying, \nFive golden rings, \nFour calling birds, \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the seventh day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nSeven swans a-swimming, \nSix geese a-laying, \nFive golden rings, \nFour calling birds, \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the eighth day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nEight maids a-milking, \nSeven swans a-swimming, \nSix geese a-laying, \nFive golden rings, \nFour calling birds, \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the ninth day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nNine ladies dancing, \nEight maids a-milking, \nSeven swans a-swimming, \nSix geese a-laying, \nFive golden rings, \nFour calling birds, \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the tenth day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nTen lords a-leaping, \nNine ladies dancing, \nEight maids a-milking, \nSeven swans a-swimming, \nSix geese a-laying, \nFive golden rings, \nFour calling birds, \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the eleventh day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nEleven pipers piping, \nTen lords a-leaping, \nNine ladies dancing, \nEight maids a-milking, \nSeven swans a-swimming, \nSix geese a-laying, \nFive golden rings, \nFour calling birds, \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree. \n\nOn the twelfth day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me \nTwelve drummers drumming, \nEleven pipers piping, \nTen lords a-leaping, \nNine ladies dancing, \nEight maids a-milking, \nSeven swans a-swimming, \nSix geese a-laying, \nFive golden rings, \nFour calling birds, \nThree French hens, \nTwo turtle doves, \nAnd a partridge in a pear tree!  \n\nDownload Hooplakidz Songs on iTunes:\nhttp://itunes.apple.com/us/album/hoopla-kidz/id439987868\n\nBecome a Hooplakidz Fan on Facebook:\nhttp://www.facebook.com/hooplakidz',
                                         u'title': u'12 Days of Christmas | Christmas Carols by Hooplakidz'},
                          u'publishedAt': u'2011-12-15T08:59:29.000Z',
                          u'tags': [u'12 days of christmas',
                                    u'Twelve Days Of Christmas (Holiday Period)',
                                    u'christmas carols',
                                    u'Christmas Carol (Composition Type)',
                                    u'christmas carols songs',
                                    u'christmas carols for children',
                                    u'christmas carols for kids',
                                    u'christmas songs',
                                    u'christmas songs for children',
                                    u'Christmas Music (Musical Genre)',
                                    u'Christmas (Holiday)',
                                    u'hooplakidz'],
                          u'thumbnails': {u'default': {u'height': 90,
                                                       u'url': u'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KQEOBZLx-Z8/default.jpg',
                                                       u'width': 120},
                                          u'high': {u'height': 360,
                                                    u'url': u'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KQEOBZLx-Z8/hqdefault.jpg',
                                                    u'width': 480},
                                          u'maxres': {u'height': 720,
                                                      u'url': u'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KQEOBZLx-Z8/maxresdefault.jpg',
                                                      u'width': 1280},
                                          u'medium': {u'height': 180,
                                                      u'url': u'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KQEOBZLx-Z8/mqdefault.jpg',
                                                      u'width': 320},
                                          u'standard': {u'height': 480,
                                                        u'url': u'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KQEOBZLx-Z8/sddefault.jpg',
                                                        u'width': 640}},
                          u'title': u'12 Days of Christmas | Christmas Carols by Hooplakidz'}}],
 u'kind': u'youtube#videoListResponse',
 u'pageInfo': {u'resultsPerPage': 1, u'totalResults': 1}}
```

To get the title and categoryId:

```
r = requests.get(url.format(id=_id, api_key=DEVELOPER_KEY))
js = r.json()
items = js["items"][0]
print (items["snippet"]["categoryId"])
print (items["snippet"]["title"])
```

Output:

```
1
12 Days of Christmas | Christmas Carols by Hooplakidz
```

This will allow you to do it all programmatically, creating a mapping of id to category name:

```
import requests

def get_data(key, region, *ids):
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={ids}&key={api_key}"
    r = requests.get(url.format(ids=",".join(ids), api_key=key))
    js = r.json()
    items = js["items"]
    cat_js = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&regionCode={}&key={}".format(region,
        key)).json()
    categories = {d['id']: d["snippet"]['title'] for d in cat_js["items"]}
    for item in items:
        yield item["snippet"]["title"], categories[item["snippet"]["categoryId"]]
```

If we run it by passing in he required args we get:

```
In [86]: for title, cat in get_data(DEVELOPER_KEY, "IE",  "KQEOBZLx-Z8", "ALTc-Cqz650"):
   ....:         print(title, cat)
   ....:     
(u'12 Days of Christmas | Christmas Carols by Hooplakidz', u'Film & Animation')
(u'Conor Mcgregor Favorite to win Rematch against Nate Diaz,Lesnar on Drug addiction,Ali Funeral', u'Sports')
```

Comment: Hey, this doesn't seem to give the title and genre. I had tried a similar piece of code before. It gives a huge list full of useless information. How should I obtain that? Plus, I see that you've used the ID instead of the url in youtube_search("KQEOBZLx-Z8"). How can I do it using the url?

Comment: It does give the title, look through the json returned. All the valid fields are in the link and there are multiple examples on that page also. You have the id in the url so why can't you use it?

Comment: I only want the name of the main url that is running with url http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQEOBZLx-Z8 or id KQEOBZLx-Z8. How do I know which one of the list is that one. Try opening the url. Does the list also show the recommended ones?

Comment: @Blabber, see the edit, you will see all the recommendations in the json

Comment: Hey, when I meant recommended ones, I was asking whether the list of your previous code's output showed recomendations. Thank a lot for so much! I didn't want this output though. I just wanted the name of the song and the genre/category as suggested in the question. Thanks anyway sir!

Comment: I have managed to get the title, it's just the genre that's posing a problem!

Comment: I used your previous code for that :) I am yet to figure how to find the category though i.e. Music, Sports, etc.

Comment: Check my answer. I couldn't seem to edit, hence the answer.

Comment: @Blabber, the gdata api  i.e v2 is deprecated, it no longer works.

Comment: I know. So what is the alternative to this?

Comment: @Blabber, have you actually looked at my answer? The alternative is the whole point of it

Comment: Yes, each number is mapped to a certain category so you can get all the need using the api as shown in my answer

Comment: Hey, is there also a way to convert the catefory Id to the category i.e.10 to Music, etc.

Comment: I'm doing it manually for now. Like creating a dict and then... mapping.

Comment: I am working on a function to do it  automatically, I will edit when done

Comment: I've done it manually. But yes, it'll probably be good to learn something new and if there's something there already. Thanks a lot man! I'm also looking myself!

Comment: (Y) Great! Thanks again.

Comment: is there a way to extract the tv show name/movie name from the netflix url using python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204272/obtain-title-of-tv-show-movie-from-netflix-url